# What's the real difference between EntityState.Deleted and Remove() method? When to use each of them?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm kinda confused about recognizing a disconnected scenario and a connected scenario, I've searched the internet but I couldn't find any real answer to my questions, I'm kinda confused about entities tracking system, connected and disconnected scenarios, when should I use the `Attach` method and also in differences between using the `Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted` and `Remove(entity)` method, and while I was searching about the last one, most of the time, they were thought identical, but it didn't match with the test that I did and what I expected

I just made a simple console app to test the differences, and how it works is that I make a person completely outside of the context instantiation scope and then pass it to the `AddPerson` method, because I think this makes a disconnected scenario, right? because the `Remove` method will complain about why I haven't attached the entity first, so I think that tells us that we're in a disconnected scenario, I'm not sure tho

This is the app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person()
        {
            PersonID = 1,
            Name = "John",
            Family = "Doe"
        };

        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            // Why this one requires attaching but the code below doesn't
            context.Person.Attach(person);
            context.Person.Remove(person);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // This method of deleting works fine without the entity being attached
            context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            context.SaveChanges();

            var people = context.Person.ToList();

            foreach (var p in people)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"PersonID: {p.PersonID} | Name: {p.Name} | Family: {p.Family}");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

so for the `Remove` method, I have to `Attach` the entity first, otherwise, it will throw an exception, BUT when I use the `Entry(person).state = EntityState.Deleted` without attaching it, it works fine, and deletes the person, now why is that, isn't this a big difference? why is it not said anywhere, I've read some websites and some other similar questions on Stackoverflow too, but this wasn't said anywhere, and for the most part, these two were presumed to be the same, and do the same thing, yes they both delete the entity, but how can we describe what happened in this test, isn't this a difference between these two?

I have two questions but I think they're related to each other, so I'm just going to ask both of them here:

1. When does exactly a disconnected scenario happen, and how can I recognize it, does it depend on the scope of the context instantiation, or on retrieving the entity directly from the context and then modifying it (with no need to attach it), or using an entity from outside of the context (like passing it from another scope to our context as a parameter, as I did in my test)?
2. Why does the `Remove` method requires attaching but the `EntityState.Deleted` doesn't, but they're presumed identical? why should I even bother to attach the entity first, while setting the state to deleted works without needing to attach, so **When to use each of them?**

Basically, The way I assume that how all these work (with my current understanding of Entity Framework which is probably wrong) is that when you're in a disconnected scenario, you have to `attach` your entity first, but then setting the state to `EntityState.Deleted` doesn't need attaching, so then why does the `Remove` method exists at all, we could use the other way of deleting all the time.

**EDIT:**
Based on the second code block in the accepted answer, I wrote this test, to figure out how it's working, you said that the `otherPersonReference` is equal to having a `Attach(Person)` but when I first attach the person and try to use `EntityState.Deleted` It works then too, and it'll delete it, but you said that it would fail, I'm a little confused :s

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person()
        {
            PersonID = 3,
            Name = "John",
            Family = "Doe"
        };

        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            //var pr = context.Person.Single(p => p.PersonID == 3);
            context.Person.Attach(person);
            context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

if I uncomment the pr variable line and then comment the `context.Person.Attach(person)` then setting the EntityState to Deleted would fail and it'll throw an exception as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `context.Entry(person).State` tells EF to start tracking the "person" instance if it isn't already tracking it. You would get an error if the DbContext was already tracking an instance for the same record.

For example, you can try the following:

```
var person = new Person { Id = 100 };  // assume an existing record with ID = 100;

using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works as you expect... However, if you were to have code that did this:

```
var person = new Person { Id = 100 };  // assume an existing record with ID = 100;

using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var otherPersonReference = context.Persons.Single(x => x.Id == 100);
    context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Your attempt to use `context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Deleted;` would fail because the context is now already tracking an entity with that ID. It's the same behaviour as if you were to try and call `Attach(person)`.

When dealing with short-lived DbContexts (such as when using `using()` blocks) and single entity operations, it can be reasonably safe to work with detached entity references, but this will get a lot more "iffy" once you start dealing with multiple possible entity references (I.e. working with lists or objects sharing references etc.) and/or calls across a DbContext which may already be tracking entity references from previous operations / iterations.

Edit: Working with detached references can be problematic and you need to take extra care when doing so. My general recommendation is to avoid it wherever possible. The approach I recommend when dealing with entities is that you should never pass an entity outside of the scope of the DbContext that read it. This means leveraging a ViewModel or DTO to represent entity-sourced details *outside* the scope of the DbContext. A detached EF Entity
*can* certainly work, but with a DTO it is explicitly clear that the data cannot be confused with a tracked entity. When it comes to performing operations like a Delete, you only really need to pass the ID.

For example, leveraging Automapper to help translate between DTOs and entities:

```
PersonDTO AddPerson(PersonDTO details)
{
    if(details == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("details");

    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        // TODO: Add validations such as verifying unique name/dob etc.

        var person = Mapper.Map<Person>(details); // Creates a new Person.
        context.Persons.Add(person);
        context.SaveChanges(); 
        details.PersonId = person.PersonId; // After SaveChanges we can retrieve the new row's ID.
        return details;
    }
}

PersonDTO UpdatePerson(PersonDTO details)
{
    if(details == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("details");

    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var existingPerson = context.Persons.Single(x => x.PersonId == details.PersonId); // Throws if we pass an invalid PersonId.
        Mapper.Map(details, existingPerson); // copies values from our DTO into Person. Mapping is configured to only copy across allowed values.
        context.SaveChanges(); 
        return Mapper.Map<PersonDTO>(existingPerson); // Return a fresh, up to date DTO of our data record.
    }
}

void DeletePerson(int personId)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var existingPerson = context.Persons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == details.PersonId);
        if (existingPerson == null)
            return; // Nothing to do.

        // TODO: Verify whether the current user should be able to delete this person or not. (I.e. based on the state of the person, is it in use, etc.)
        context.Persons.Remove(existingPerson);
        context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

In this example a Person entity does not ever leave the scope of a DbContext. The trouble with detached entities is that whenever passing an entity around to other methods and such, those methods might assume they are working with attached, complete or complete-able (i.e. through lazy loading) entities. Was the entity loaded from a DbContext that is still "alive" so if if the code wants to check person.Address that data is either eager loaded and available, or lazy-loadable? vs. #null which could mean the person does not have an address, or that without a DbContext or lazy loading we cannot determine whether it does or not. As a general rule if a method is written to accept an entity, it should always expect to have a complete, or complete-able version of that entity. Not a detached "maybe complete, maybe not" instance, not a "new"ed up instance of a class that has some arbitrary values populated, (rather than an entity representing a data row) and not a deserialized block of JSON coming from a web client. All of those can be typed as a "Person" entity, but *not* a Person entity.

Edit 2: "Complete" vs. "Complete-able"
A Complete entity is an entity that has *all* related entities eager loaded. Any method that accepts a Person should be able to access any property, including navigation properties, and receive the true value. If the Person has an Address, then a #null address should only ever mean that person does not have an address (if that is valid), not "that person does not have an address, or it just wasn't loaded." This also goes for cases where you might have a method that accepts an entity, which you haven't loaded, but want to substitute with a entity class populated with an ID and whatever data you might have on hand. That incomplete "entity" could find itself sent to other methods that expect a more complete entity. Methods should never need to guess at what they receive.

A Complete-able entity is an entity where any related entities within that entity can be lazy loaded if accessed. The consuming method doesn't need to determine whether properties are available or not, it can access Person.Address and it will always get an Address if that person is supposed to have one, whether the caller remembered to eager load it or not.

Where methods are using tightly scoped DbContexts (`using()`) if you return an entity then there is no way that you can guarantee later down the call-chain that this entity is complete-able. Today you can make the assurance that all properties are eager-loaded, but tomorrow a new relationship could be added leaving a navigation property somewhere within the object graph that might not be remembered to be eager-loaded.

Eager loading is also expensive, given to ensure an entity is "complete", everything needs to be loaded, whether the consumers ever need it or not. Lazy Loading was introduced to facilitate this, however, in many cases this is extremely expensive leading to a LOT of chatter with the database and the introduction of performance costs when the model evolves. Elements like serialization (a common problem in web applications) touch every property by default leading to numerous lazy load calls for every entity sent.

DTOs/ViewModels are highly recommended when data needs to leave the scope of a DbContext as it ensures only the data a consumer needs is loaded, but equally importantly, as a model may evolve, you avoid lazy loading pitfalls. Serializing a DTO rather than an Entity will ensure those new relationships don't come into play until a DTO is updated to actually need that data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in the second code block, how would you delete the person when it's being used by `otherPersonRef` variable, but I don't think that this variable is quite equal to `Attach(person)` method because I tested the second code block and I tried `Remove(person)` but it threw an exception saying that it couldn't find it in the ObjectStateManager, and then it also doesn't let the `EntityState.Deleted` to delete the person, I'm confused if the person is being tracked or not

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. References are extremely important when working with EF entities. You can have two objects representing the exact same data, but as separate references, an EF DbContext can only work with one of them. `Attach(entity)` will attempt to associate a reference with the DbContext. Calling `DbContext.Entry(entity).State = ...` will also attempt to associate that reference to the DbContext. Both will succeed if the DbContext is *not* already tracking a reference to that entity, both will fail if it is.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to cover off examples for Add, Update, and Delete leveraging a DTO rather than passing detached entities around, and the reasons why you should consider avoiding passing detached entities.

Comment: Thanks for adding details, but why do the Add and Update methods return a PersonDTO? and what do you mean by a Complete or Complete-able entity?

Comment: They don't need to return anything, but the point was to demonstrate that they should not return an "Entity" if the DbContext scope ends within the methods. I'll add a definition of complete vs. complete-able within the answer.

Comment: I edited my question, and added the test that I wrote about the second code block in your answer, first I attached a Person object, and then I tried to set its EntityState to Deleted but that worked too! but you had said that it would fail if the object is being tracked already, so this violates the difference that I thought they had, that `EntityState.Deleted` will first attach the entity, and then deletes it, and if it's already attached, it would fail, but the `Remove(entity)` needs the `Attach(entity)` beforehand

Comment: Well answered. Just one little improvement IMHO: The Add() method should also use AutoMapper to create a fresh instance from the new entity and not manually edit the existing incoming instance. Even better, there should be individual DTOs for create and update. Cause in your example a malicious user could also provide an ID for the the Add method. If the Add() method input parameter type would be a different type without that property, there is no chance of injecting an Id.

Comment: Add and update can use different DTOs. `Mapper.Map<TEntity>(dto)` will create a new entity instance using the mapped fields from the DTO. The mapping, whether insert or update, should never attempt to copy over the PK property, even FK properties should be ignored if used. If EF is configured to use Identity columns, any ID value in the DTO would be ignored.  Any FK passed in needs to be validated, typically by fetching it by the context to resolve a navigation property after the initial creation by `.Map`. It's reasonably safe from tampering, but if in doubt, validate. :)

Comment: @StevePy Excuse me, can you correct me if I'm wrong? you're saying that the difference is this... but with the test that I did, it looks like that it's simply not. am I doing anything wrong in my code? or did I not understand your explanation? I appreciate the detailed explanation in your answer but I don't know if your answer actually answers my main question or not, I tested what you said, and it's not working like that, so I still don't know the difference between these.

Comment: Your code will work *if* you can guarantee that the instance attached to the DbContext does *not* have another tracked instance representing the same data row. In the simplest examples that will work, but it is a potentially dangerous assumption that can catch you out in other scenarios. Having a Delete method that accepts an ID means a smaller payload for the method and avoids any assumptions associated with detached entities. The second example is just a demonstration of if the Context is already tracking an instance of the same data and trying to perform an attach via Entity.State.