# Is there a better way to include additional fields/columns in EF Core without loading the whole navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-5.0

Is there a better way to  include additional fields/columns in EF Core without loading the whole navigation property

i have two entities say Employee and Department.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ... more fields.
}
```

i need to return list of Employees to the client, but i dont want to include the whole Department entity which is only for server side process, except the `DepartmentId` and `DepartmentName`.

i have two solutions.

Solution 1 is to use calculated property and navigation property.

```
public class Employee
{
    // ...
    
    public string DepartmentName
    {
        get
        {
            if (Department != null)
            {
                return Department.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Query for department name but also have to include all fields.
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(MyDbContext context)
{
    return context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department).ToList();
}
```

solution 2 is to use dynamic joining.

```
public class Employee
{
    // ...
    
    [NotMapped]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

// Query for department name without navigation property.
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(MyDbContext context)
{
    Func<Employee, Department, Employee> map = (em, dept) =>
    {
        em.DepartmentName = dept.Name;
        return em;
    };
    var query = from em in context.Employees
                join dept in context.Departments on em.DepartmentId equals dept.Id
                select map(em, dept);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

but if there 're more foreign fields to include, the linq query will be tedious. Another problem is, this is not generic way for arbitrary entity, and i have more entities to implement like above.

i want to know if there's any other elegent implementation or official way.

Comment: You have a controller with multiple types of responses.  Each response is a different Action.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1):

For methods which are running within the scope of a DbContext, as appears to be your case by passing through the DbContext instance, I would recommend having them return `IQueryable<TEntity>` rather than `List<TEntity>`. In this way the consumers can further refine the query as they see fit. This includes projecting the entity structure into what is needed, (Needing just a DepartmentName) handling things like sorting, pagination, etc. This is commonly the case when developing a Repository pattern.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ... more fields.
}

// Then somewhere in a Repository class...

public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(MyDbContext context)
{
    return context.Employees.AsQueryable();
}
```

The first question that usually comes up is "what's the point? why not just use the DbContext?". There can be two good reasons for implementing a repository pattern like this. Firstly to enable unit testing. Mocking a DbContext is "messy", where-as mocking a dependency that has a method that returns `IQueryable<Employee>` is easy. The other reason is that systems often have low level rules to enforce, such as systems that use soft-delete (i.e. `IsActive=false` rather than deleting rows) or multi-tenancy. (I.e. employees for multiple ClientId that access the system) Repositories can serve as excellent boundaries to ensure these low-level rules are enforced.

```
public static IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(MyDbContext context, bool includeInactive = false)
{
    var clientId = ClientService.ResolveCurrentUserClient();
    var query context.Employees.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId);
    if(!includeInactive)
        query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive);
    return query;
}
```

In the above example the ClientService would be a dependency that is configured to check the current user and their association to a tenancy client to filter data by, then optionally filter out only active rows.

If you're not planning on implementing unit tests and have no low level rules to enforce, then my recommendation would be to just use the DbContext than adding a layer of abstraction.

When it comes to methods that return data outside of the DbContext's scope, the best solution I can recommend is to use projection to return a data object (View Model or DTO) rather than an entity. The view model can represent only the data your consumer needs and you can either leverage `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` to populate it directly from an `IQueryable` resulting in a minimum sized payload and maximum performance.

```
[Serializable]
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public static MapperConfigurationExpression BuildMapExpression(MapperConfigurationExpression expression = null)
    {
        if (expression == null)
            expression = new MapperConfigurationExpression();

        expression.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.DepartmentId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Department.Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.DepartmentName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Department.Name));
        return expression;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller action or other method that would serialize our Employee & Department info:

```
public ViewResult List()
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(EmployeeViewModel.BuildMapExpression());
        var employees = EmployeeRepository.GetEmployees(context)
            .ProjectTo<EmployeeViewModel>(config)
            .ToList(); // Consider pagination /w Skip/Take
        return View(employees);
    }
}
```

So rather than serializing an Employee entity and worrying about the serializer lazy loading data or having a bunch of #null references, the method packaging up the data would project the resulting `IQueryable` down into a DTO or ViewModel class that is safe for serialization. This produces highly efficient queries for both performance and memory use. I cover off why to avoid sending entities beyond the scope of their DBContext and why they should always be considered complete, or complete-able in my response to this question:
[What's the real difference between EntityState.Deleted and Remove() method? When to use each of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439211/whats-the-real-difference-between-entitystate-deleted-and-remove-method-when/68447353#68447353)

Answer (score 0):

If I need to load only certain properties I usually go this way . Add to employee class extra property DepartmentName and add attribute [NotMaped]  (or Ignore in fluent)

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    .......

    [NotMapped]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

action

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(MyDbContext context)
{
    return context.Employees
                      .Select(e=> new Employee
                       {
                         Id=e.Id,
                         Name=e.Name,
                         DepartmentName=e.Department.Name 
                        }).ToList();
}
```

I don't like to use mapper, it is very limited, so if I need to include  lots of properties I usually to this

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(MyDbContext context)
{
  var employees= context.Employees
                      .Include(i=> Department)
                      .ToList();

   foreach(var item in employees)
  { 
           item.DepartmentName=item.Department.Name 
           .....
           ..... another calculated fiels if needed

           item.Department=null;
      }
    return employees;
}
```

Comment: I want to down vote, but it is a valid response. After putting some effort in my own APIs to do this I have found that these endpoints become rarely used instead callers get more flexibility from IQueryable<T> responses and they can do their own projections.